# Cast into a querybuilder

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony-2.6

I have a querybuilder like this:

```
        ->andWhere('i.createdAt LIKE :date')
        ->setParameter('date', $date.'%')
```

The field created_at is a DateTime and my $date is a string.
Is there any way to cast my created_at as a string ?

I've already tried :

```
            ->andWhere('i.createdAt::text LIKE :date')
```

Console :

```
.... has no field or association named createdAt::text
```

Or :

```
            ->andWhere('to_char(i.createdAt) LIKE :date')
```

Console :

```
  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 208: Error: Expected known function, got 'to_char'
```

Or

```
  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 208: Error: Expected known function, got 'cast'
```

I'm using Symfony 2.6 and postgreSQL.

Thanks you :)

Comment: How do you expect to search date with `like`?

Comment: My created_at's date are like this : " 2018-08-01". 

And for some reason, i'm trying to search dates with a string like this : " 2018-01 "

(who contains the year and month)

Comment: So make a query `WHERE year(fieldName) == your_year AND month(fieldName) == your_month`. `year()` and `month()` are functions which extract data from datetype field. Maybe they have other names in postgres, it's up to you to discover.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with doctrine extensions bundle :)
https://packagist.org/packages/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

format the date to a string like so:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Or leave out the day and  time since it's a LIKE query

```
$date->format('Y-m-') . '%'
```

Consider however querying with dates between a start and an end point:

```
$nextMonth = clone $date;
$nextMonth->modify('+1 month');
```

Then you can do a greater or equal to first date and less than or equal to the end date

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you, that's a great idea.

```
    $startInterval = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', $date);
    $endInterval = clone $startInterval;
    $endInterval->modify('+1 month');
```

This is a way better !

```
        ->andWhere('i.createdAt > :startInterval')
        ->andWhere('i.createdAt < :endInterval')
        ->setParameter('startInterval', $startInterval)
        ->setParameter('endInterval', $endInterval)
```